Project validation failed: tasks : Cast to [undefined] failed for value \"[]\" (type string) at path
I have been working on a project management tool. I created a mongoose schema for the Project. But when I test it using Postman it throws an error. I tried almost everything and spent hours debugging but all in vain. Here is the exact error:
Project validation failed: tasks: Cast to [undefined] failed for value \"[]\" (type string) at path \"tasks.0\" because of \"TypeError\
EDIT 1: Downgraded the mongoose version from 8 to 5.7.7 and it worked.
I have tried almost everything. May be I missed something but i spent hours but nothing worked out for me. 1. When I removed both collaborators and tasks array it worked fine
2. I have used and define schema directly in this file like this:
tasks: [taskSchema]
but that time i encounter another error
cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') mongoose
Please help me how can i get a away with these errors. I am using mongoose version ^8.3.2.
Below are my files:
Project.model.js:


const projectSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
      collaborators: [
      {
        user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
        },
        permissions: {
          type: String,
          enum: ['read', 'write', 'admin'],
          default: 'read',
        },
      },
    ],
    tasks: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Task',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);
const Project = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);

module.exports = Project;

project.controller.js:
const createProject = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const project = await projectService.createProject(req.body, req.user.id);
  res.status(httpStatus.CREATED).json(project);
});

services.js:
const createProject = async (projectBody, userId) => {
  const project = await Project.create({ ...projectBody, user: userId });
  return project;
};````


In your projectBody variable you will most likely have a key: value pair of "tasks" : "[]" somewhere in that object. You think you are passing an empty array but you are just passing the string characters ",[,],". I suspect you are json encoding the contents of projectBody somewhere before passing it to Project.create.


Project validation failed: tasks: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[]" (type string) at path "tasks.0" because of "TypeError\

Seems like you are passing an empty String instead of an empty array for the tasks field.
services.js
const createProject = async (projectBody, userId) => {
  const tasks = Array.isArray(projectBody.tasks) ? projectBody.tasks : [];
  const project = await Project.create({ ...projectBody, user: userId, tasks });
  return project;
};
    
tasks: {
      type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], // Define tasks as an array of ObjectIds
      ref: 'Task',
      default: [], // Here, you can pass as an empty array.
    },


It is identical to what I have already.

can you please check this line? You need to add what is the name of the object you miss that
user: {           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,           ref: 'User',         },

yeah, sorry you are right I have this in my code but may be I made a mistake in posting the question let me edit. I am still getting the same error and I don't know what should I do: Project validation failed: tasks: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[]" (type string) at path "tasks.0" because of "TypeError""

Okay, so in this case what you can try is : initialize your taks as an empty array.
const tasks = projectBody.tasks || []; inside services.js

Now I am getting double error. Project validation failed: tasks: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[]" (type string) at path "tasks.0" because of "TypeError", tasks.0: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[]" (type string) at path "tasks.0" because of "TypeError""
it is repeated twice.

Here is the stack trace it might help..
ValidationError: Project validation failed: tasks: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[]" (type string) at path "tasks.0" because of "TypeError"\n    at Document.invalidate (C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\fyp\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3289:32)\n    at applyDefaults

Okay, may be you need to change the schema passing the default value as an empty array. Updated in answer can you try that once . Update your schema .

I have updated the schema and also add default array but it is throwing following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')\n    at cloneArray
I also try some examples from past projects and even from the web but nothing seems to work if the document is nested. I think there is something wrong with the node modules or may with the version.

not sure what's wrong. It's weird but maybe what we can try is let's say task field is an empty array, default to an empty array. and if data is not provided then we can assign null.
const tasks = Array.isArray(projectBody.tasks) ? projectBody.tasks : [];
can you try this code.

Nothing changed, same error.

try to dubug  or we can debug together if you can connect

Thanks, Yes sure let me debug if the issue persist I will connect with you.

I can't believe this I spent my whole day debugging the issue and found out it is because of the version I downgraded the version from 8 to 5.7.7 and it worked. I am famous node + expresses boilerplate and I updated the Mongoose version previously but didn't think it would cause me so much pain. By the thanks for your time kedar. I really appreciate i.

Okay great.......
